# fetch json data from blob storage in web activity using azure data factory

Tags: c#, .net-core, azure-cosmosdb, azure-data-factory

i need to pass dynamic data in body in POST method od web activity using azure data factory.
My data source point is in Blob Storage from i am storing json data .I need to pass ID in body.
I am doing this inside for each loop.
I have also created linkedservices.
I am passing like this as shown below in body.But i am not getting proper value.

```
{
 "data":{"date":@formatDateTime(convertTimeZone(utcnow(), 'UTC', 'GMT Standard Time'),'yyyy-MM-dd'),"id":@item},
 "meta": {
    "pagination": {
      "page_size": 200
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use this expression to have a try:

```
{ "data":{"date":@{formatDateTime(convertTimeZone(utcnow(), 'UTC', 'GMT Standard Time'),'yyyy-MM-dd')},"id":@{item()}}, "meta": { "pagination": { "page_size": 200 } } }
```

Result in my web application:

[image]

Comment: That's [Dynamic content edition](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-expression-language-functions#dynamic-content-editor), you have to wrap your expression in `@{ ... }`. Like `{ "name": "@{toUpper('myData')} }"`.